# Combine multiple html rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following two tables

Blog

```
Id Title
1  My Blog Title
```

BlogContent

```
Id Blogid Content
1    1   <p>My First Paragraph</p>
2    1   <p>My Second Paragraph</p>
```

Each Blog Entry may have multiple Content entries. This is a `varchar` field that contains HTML content. I need to select a blog and all of its content combined together.

here is what I tried:

```
SELECT B.Id, B.Title, 
STUFF(( SELECT '' + BC.Content 
        FROM BlogContent BC 
        WHERE B.Id = BC.Blogid
        ORDER BY BC.Id ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') AS Content
FROM Blog B
WHERE B.Id = 1
ORDER BY B.PublishDate DESC
```

And it almost worked, this is my result:

```
Id   Title             Content
1    My Blog Title     &lt;p&gt;This is the first Message&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is the second Message&lt;/p&gt;
```

My problem with the code above is that everything became HTML Encoded, I assume its because of `FOR XML`. How can I achieve combining without adding this part? If I don't add it then I get an error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I get the following result:

```
Id   Title             Content
1    My Blog Title     <p>This is the first Message</p><p>This is the second Message</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ID in BlogContent is the proper sequence.

**Example**

```
Declare @Blog table (ID int, Title varchar(max))
Insert Into @Blog values
(1,'My Blog Title')

Declare @BlogContent table (ID int,Blogid int, Content varchar(max))
Insert Into @BlogContent values
(1,1,'<p>My First Paragraph</p>'),
(2,1,'<p>My Second Paragraph</p>')


Select A.*
      ,Content  = Stuff((Select '' +Content 
                           From  @BlogContent 
                           Where Blogid=A.ID 
                           Order by ID 
                           For XML Path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
                        ,1,0,'') 
 From @Blog A
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Title           Content
1   My Blog Title   <p>My First Paragraph</p><p>My Second Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works as I would like it to. Would you please explain to me the `FOR XML` and `.value` part as I don't understand how this works.

Comment: Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries

Comment: @Bojan The type directive essentially allow what appears to be XML data to be processed and the ,value() simply returns the string value.