# Concatenate nvarchar column and convert to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am currently fetching an integer row, then converting the row to a Nvarchar in a hash table, then converting this to XML. The aim is to have all values returned in the one XML variable like so:

```
<item id ="001"/><item id ="002"/><item id ="003"/><item id ="004"/><item id ="005"/>
```

Currently my code returns this as an XML row like so:

```
 col
---------------
<item id="60114" />
<item id="60116" />
<item id="60120" />
<item id="60122" />
<item id="60123" />
<item id="60124" />
<item id="60125" />
<item id="60129" />
```

Here is my code which i have anonimised:

```
DROP TABLE #ClientNumber

DECLARE @XMLClientID NVARCHAR (MAX)

CREATE TABLE #ClientNumber (ID int identity(1,1), [XMLClientID] NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #ClientNumber 
SELECT '<item id ="'+ CAST([ClientId] AS NVARCHAR) + '"/>' AS [XMLClientID] FROM [dbo.].[MyView] WHERE Column = 'Condition' AND [ClientName] LIKE 'BLA%';


WITH xoutput AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(xml, [XMLClientID]) AS col
    FROM #ClientNumber)
SELECT *
 FROM xoutput
```

Any steer would be great as the stuff will not work due to the for XML.

Comment: You can use STUFF with XML.  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327612/combine-multiple-html-rows-into-one/49327865#49327865

Comment: I do not really get what you want... Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you provide is - at least for me - not enough to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use integer values instead of convert and format it.

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl (id int);

 INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (60114), (60116), (60120), (60122)
 GO

 SELECT id
 FROM tbl item
 FOR XML AUTO
```

Output:

```
| XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B                                 |
| :----------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| <item id="60114"/><item id="60116"/><item id="60120"/><item id="60122"/> |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9fb1a7f81d01b7c0811ea9a98aa18770)*

Comment: Thanks McNets. How would i get <item id="60114"/><item id="60116"/><item id="60120"/><item id="60122"/> in to a variable using the above code.

Comment: @VKrishan this way: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ee83ff3484cbd9909efe729aa47977b

Comment: Your solution is way more simpler than mine. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @table table (col varchar(100))
insert into @table values
('<item id="60114" />'),
('<item id="60116" />'),
('<item id="60120" />'),
('<item id="60122" />'),
('<item id="60123" />'),
('<item id="60124" />'),
('<item id="60125" />'),
('<item id="60129" />')

select cast(col as xml) from @table for xml path('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @John Cappelletti for the link. Here is my solution:

```
DECLARE @XMLClientID VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @StringClientID VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @XMLStringClient XML;


CREATE TABLE #ClientNumber (ID int identity(1,1), [XMLClientID] VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #ClientNumber
--AMEND LINE BELOW TO SELECT TARGETS!!--
SELECT '<item id ="'+ CAST([ClientId] AS NVARCHAR) + '"/>' AS [XMLClientID] FROM [dbo.].[MyView] WHERE Column = 'Condition' AND [ClientName] LIKE 'BLA%';


SELECT DISTINCT [XMLClientID]  = STUFF((Select '' +[XMLClientID] 
                           FROM  #ClientNumber
                           FOR XML Path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1,0,'') 
                                            INTO #TempString
                                            FROM #ClientNumber A
SET @StringClientID = (SELECT [XMLClientID] FROM #TempString)
SET @XMLStringClient = CAST(@StringClientID AS XML);

EXEC dbo.My_StoredProcedure @XMLStringClient
```